# What is the resolved default location mongod.exe looks for the configuration in?

Tags: windows, configuration, mongodb, defaults

Trying to do a minimal configuration of mongod, and I would like to use the 'natural' pathing structure for the location of the config file.

To give an example on what I am looking for, here are the equivalent paths for some other popular programs:

- Apache: ../conf/httpd.conf
- MySQL: ../my.ini
- PHP: ./php.ini
- OpenSSL: ./openssl.cnf

For mongo, I am finding mixed information on the name of the file itself, and it appears to support yaml as well as your typical key<>value format.

I am aware that all of these programs have a force switch (including mongo) to specify the config file name and location, however this is not what I am looking for.

I have been through these (and a bunch of other resources, but these appear to come 'closest')

- [Install mongodb on Windows](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)
- [Configuration options](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/configuration-options/)

And then there is [Configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/) which is informative as to the formats of the config file, but not where it should be located or what it should be named if not using the parameter to force the location of the config file.